# Dynamic Linq Group By UnixTime

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, group-by, unix-timestamp

**I am using Dynamic Linq. Group By works fine like this:**

```
var groupedData = resultSet.AsQueryable().GroupBy("Username", "it").Select("new (it.Key as key, it.Count() as count)");
```

**But I want to use unixtime column as key for grouping. Example table:**

CreatedDate(integer)

```
1419258192 (22/12/2014 14:23:12)  
1419292800 (23/12/2014 00:00:00)  
1419349440 (23/12/2014 15:44:00)  
1419379200 (24/12/2014 00:00:00)
```

**What I want as a result:**

```
22/12/2014: 1  
23/12/2014: 2  
24/12/2014: 1
```

Comment: Well it sounds like you want the *date* here, not just the date/time. Do you really need to be using anything dynamic here? Everything looks static to me...

Comment: what type of `CreateDate`?  string?

Comment: @JonSkeet I wrote "CreatedDate" but it is just for example. It is dynamic and can be any column.

Comment: @Tim.Tang its integer.

Comment: Okay, and what time zone do you want this to use in order to break date/time values into dates?

Comment: @JonSkeet GMT+2 but UTC will also work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to get out of the dynamic part as quickly as possible. You can then convert to `DateTime` and use the `Date` part for the grouping. If you need to be dynamic in the field name, you can do that, but end up with an `IEnumerable<long>` for further work:

```
var groupedData = resultSet.AsQueryable()
                           .Select("CreatedDate")
                           .AsEnumerable<long>()
                           .GroupBy(UnixTimestampToDate)
                           .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

...
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch =
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

private static DateTime UnixTimestampToDate(long timestamp)
{
    return UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(timestamp)
                    .Date;
}
```

If you need to convert to a different time zone, you could do that in `UnixTimestampToDate`... or make it part of the query itself by just converting from the unix timestamp to a UTC `DateTime` *without* calling `Date`, then transforming to a different time zone, then taking the date afterwards.